# How to Separate Data from Multiple Devices on Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I am currently trying to connect 2 different devices to the IoT Hub, and I need to separate the data from each device. In order to do so, I tried configuring my stream analytics query like this:

```
SELECT
    deviceId, temperature, humidity, CAST(iothub.EnqueuedTime AS datetime) AS event_date
INTO
    NodeMCUOutput
FROM
    iothubevents
WHERE
    deviceId = "NodeMCU1"
```

However, for some reason, the output is not shown if the WHERE statement is in the code (the outputs are shown without it, but the data is not filtered). I need the WHERE statement in order to sort the data the way I want it. Am I missing something? Are there any solutions to this? Thanks a lot. Cheers!

Comment: If the deviceId is the one from IoT Hub, Matthijs answer below will help you to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device ID and other properties that are not in the message itself are included as metadata on the message. You can read that metadata using the `GetMetadataPropertyValue()` function. This should work for you:

```
SELECT
    GetMetadataPropertyValue(iothubevents, 'IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId') as deviceId, 
    temperature, 
    humidity, 
    CAST(GetMetadataPropertyValue(iothubevents, 'IoTHub.EnqueuedTime') AS datetime) AS event_date
INTO
    NodeMCUOutput
FROM
    iothubevents
WHERE 
    GetMetadataPropertyValue(iothubevents, 'IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId') = 'NodeMCU1'
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you use a double quote in the WHERE clause.
You need a simple quote to get a match on strings. In this case it will be

```
WHERE deviceId = 'NodeMCU1'
```

If the deviceId is the one from IoT Hub metadata, Matthijs answer will help you to retrieve it.